# zf-blueprint doesn't work

Tags: zend-server-ce, zf-boilerplate

Installed Zend Server, downloaded [Blueprint](http://zf-boilerplate.com/downloads/), when trying to start application it tells me:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\zfboilerprint\library\Bisna\Application\Container\DoctrineContainer.php on line 460
```

What am I doing wrong and what do I need to get rid of this error? 
The pproblem is, I installed Zend server with php 5.3 only because I got this error also on 5.4 and before I had php 5.2 which didn't support namespaces and showed other errors, so I just can't make this product work on any version of php.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, i needed to install memcashe extension on php. Just found the dll in web and added couple of strings in php.ini